# On the inequality $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}>1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, lie-algebras, math-history

In the book Lie algebra, Humphreys, during classification of Dynkin diagrams, arrives at the equation over positive integers:
$$\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} +\frac{1}{r}>1$$
and makes a comment in bracket

> (This inequality, by the way, has a long mathematical history)

I suddenly stopped at that classification, and wondered *How long back the history goes for this inequality?*

Comment: See cases $1,2,3$ for the [generalized Fermat](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~beuke106/Fermatlectures.pdf) and its history.

Comment: Examples of places I've seen this: Solving other inequalities, Egyptian Fractions, Diophantine approximations, and and in relation to partial sums of a generalization of the Harmonic Series where we sum from $\frac 1a$ to $\frac 1b$

Comment: It has to do with finite subgroups G of SO(3) (linked to regular polyhedra) with relationship $1/p + 1/q + 1/r = 1 + 2/|G|$. Have a look at lectures in (http://www.math.miami.edu/~armstrong/686sp13.html).